# Error 404 pagina angular

Tags: angular

projeto em angular6 error 404

Ao dar um refresh na pagina ele não acha os arquivos.

error : failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

scripts.d0a977ac216f5f3f1a16.js
runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js
main.0e2f817b6b1f487e900d.js

Comment: Veja se existem os arquivos, veja se o caminho dos arquivos estão referenciados corretamente.

Comment: Qual o servidor da aplicação e você utiliza rotas?